# bootstrap menu is not showing in mobile on server

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation

I have made a responsive nav menu of bootstrap. When I use it on my local computer it works fine and shows menu even in mobile version but ever since I have uploaded it on server and when I check it on mobile its not there. Its not showing on mobile...

[http://votingdemo.enzymik.com/](http://votingdemo.enzymik.com/Home)

Here is a image of my local machine but it is not showing like this on live server. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the styles in the browser using the Developer Tools? That would tell you which styles are being overriden and what styles are applied.

Comment: Without seeing your code, the only other suggestion I can offer is to make sure your site is fetching the bootstrap.css file that displays the three lines and the jquery and bootstrap.js files that make it do stuff. Maybe you forgot to upload one of those files.